# In VS2015, why does running 'dnu' from the Package Manager Console cause my .NET Core Console application to NOT display a Console Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx, .net-core

Why does running *dnu* from the *Package Manager Console* cause my *.NET Core Console application* to fail to display a *Console Window*?

In VS2015:

1. *File->New->Project*
2. Choose *Installed->Templates->Visual C#->Web->Console Application (Package)*
3. Hit *F5* to run, and see the *Console Window* appear, which is expected

Now do the following:

1. *Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console*
2. At the *PM>* prompt, enter the following command and hit return:

   *dnu*
3. Hit *F5* again to run, and note that the *Console Window* does not appear!

This is causing problems, because I'm using the *Console Window* for output.  If I save the Visual Studio project, close Visual Studio 2015, re-open the project and hit F5, the *Console Window* appears.

I'm using this version of *dnu*:

```
PM> dnu --version
Microsoft .NET Development Utility
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16202
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   6.1
 Runtime Id:   win7-x86
```

Comment: Please open a bug in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/new). The ASP.NET tooling folks can look at this.

Comment: I opened a bug on GitHub as you suggested.  Thanks.